# IMAP via PHP: /ssl and /tls choose different TLS version

Tags: php, ssl, starttls

I'm using [z-push-contrib](https://github.com/fmbiete/Z-Push-contrib) to get emails from an IMAP server (run by me as well).

If I use the `imap_open` option `/ssl` and connect to port 993, TLS 1.2 is being used.

If I use `/tls` and connect to port 143 using STARTTLS, TLS 1.0 and a different cipher is being used.

SMTP behaves the same (STARTTLS only uses TLS 1.0)

If I use openssl from the command line, TLS 1.2 is being used:

It doesn't matter if I connect to port 993 or to 143 with STARTTLS, I always get a TLS 1.2 connection using the same strong, modern cipher.

Is this a bug in PHP's Openssl implementation?

Comment: How do you know which version is used? Did you do a packet capture to look at the ClientHello or did you check the resulting protocol after the handshake? In the last case it might be simply the server which is configured for TLS 1.0 only.

Comment: I checked the server's logs and the email-headers. As I wrote, if I connect directly via Openssl, TLV1.2 is being used as expected. The server is configured to use TLS1, TLS1.1 and TLS1.2

Comment: Since this is same OpenSSL on the client side for all tests it must be either the application using it which restricts the protocol version or the server. It's not a bug in OpenSSL itself. Is this server public so one could actually run some tests?

Comment: yes it is. I just thought it strange that port 993 uses TLS1.2 and port 143 with STARTLES only uses TLS1.0

Comment: you could check `openssl s_client` vs. `openssl -startls smtp` or `openssl -startls imap` to find out if this is a server side or client side issue.  If this is server side you would see TLS 1.2 without -starttls and TLS 1.0 with -starttls.

Comment: That's what I did. I always get TLS 1.2

Answer (score 7):

No, it's defined at the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/imap_open):

- */tls*: force use of start-TLS to encrypt the session, and reject connection to servers that do not support it
- */ssl*: use the Secure Socket Layer to encrypt the session

The difference is very subtle. Basically StatTLS connects to an unencrypted port/connection and then asks for encryption, while TLS/SSL sessions are encrypted before any text is transmitted (see [STARTTLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS)). They usually use different ports, but it's common for mail servers to support both on both ports (so they support a broader range of clients).

Cipher and TLS version choice is based on client-server negotiation, but STARTTLS could be understood as a less-capable client or server, then the parameters for decision differ.

AFAIK, there's no limitation on the usage of TLS1.1 and TLS1.2 when connecting through STARTTLS, but they do connect differently than TLS/SSL.

In doubt, use TLS/SSL, since it's more secure :)

---

**Update**

PHP IMAP extension makes use of [c-Client library](http://www.washington.edu/imap/) for IMAP protocol-specific functions. This library is somewhat outdated (2007) — and probably handles STARTTLS commands differently than calling openssl — that's why the difference in encryption/ciphers used.

Comment: I might not have made this clear, but using openssl it doesn't make a difference if I use a SSL-port like 993 or use port 143 and use STARTTLS. Both times, the same TLS version and the same cipher is being used. That's how it is supposed to work and there is no reason to use a weaker cipher or TLS version when using STARTTLS.

Comment: STARTTLS also isn't for "less-capable clients" but was thought to deprecate the need for specific SSL-ports and is therefore an improvement. http://wiki.dovecot.org/SSL 
This (I assume) is either a bad behavior in PHP's openssl or IMAP implementation or in Z-Push

Comment: Can't be sure which came first, STARTTLS (1999, see [RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2595)) or reserving port 993 for IMAP over SSL.

Comment: I really don't see STARTTLS as an upgrade, although historically it might have been treated as so. A simple man in the middle can intercept the server `250 STARTTLS` request and drop/alter it, making the full connection text/plain.

Dovecot is but one mail provider and they may enable both protocols on every port, others might handle this differently, but most accept encrypted connections on port 143 (although not as many accept non-encrypted connections on port 993)